# Sqlite3 C++ Thread SELECT

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

I am working with a huge database (For me it's huge ^^). I have 5.3 million of records. I am trying to use multithreading to reduce the time of my research. But my way is not working find.

```cpp
const std::string &&statement = this->buildStatement(params, client);
Alpaga::SQLite3::Statement s(db, statement);
while (s.step()) {
    pool.task([&, exposed = s.column<std::string>(1)] {
        this->calcDistance(matchThreshold, client.aka, exposed, Alpaga::Utils::Str::nbrWord(exposed));
    });
}
```

Statement = query (SELECT name FROM users)
So I get 5.3 of string name, and I use my threadpool to calculate the distance between 2 string (But no matter).

But I would like split my statement and like that one thread take 0 to 1 million records an other one take 1 million to 2 million, etc...

Comment: What means "calculate the distance between 2 string"? Maybe you can do it in the query itself?

Comment: For example I have 2 string "Hello" and "World" and I use an algorithm to see the percentage of compatibility. I need more than just Hello == World. But even if I don't use it it's realy slow to get my records, I need multithreading

Comment: How long does the lambda in `pool.task` take? Can't you configure multiple consumers for your pool? (whatever it is)

Comment: What do you mean by multiple consumers ?

Comment: How many threads are taking tasks from `pool` and executing them? And how long does your `calcDistance` take relative to the overhead of adding a task to the pool?

Comment: I can setup the number of threads but in my case I use 5 threads, calcDistance takes less than 0.05s

Comment: Maybe `offset` and `limit` can be useful? `SELECT name FROM users limit 3000000 offset 2000000` (different numbers for different threads). Another tricks: add `calcDistanse` as extension function; maybe you can precalculate some params e.g. `length` to reuse them on `calcDistance` call. P.S. 5.3KK rows is a not so huge for sqlite. The main problem is your code.

Comment: I will try with ```offset``` and ```limit```.